# Avoiding for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

Is there any way to avoid using below for loop in Matlab?
'M' and 'B' are 100 by 100 symmetric matrix, which it's elements are known.

```
 p1=rand(100,100).*25;
 M=p1+p1';
 p2=rand(100,100).*25;
 B=p2+p2';
 dr=0.2;
 R=2 *dr;
 for o=1:50 
 center= R*o; 
 MX= abs(M-center)<dr; 
 mm=MX.*B; 
 countB = [countm,sum(mm(:))/sum(mm(:)~=0)];
 count = [count,sum(MX(:))]; 
 end
```

*This for loop is repeating in another loop and the aim to avoid using it is to make the code faster.

Comment: What does `count` need to be? Can you add a small sample for `M` and `B` so that we can run it?

Comment: Yes I did. @10a

Comment: `countm` and `count` both not exist before you assign them in your loop, thus this code will error out. Also: ***DON'T*** grow arrays, instead, simply preallocate them and all your troubles will be gone probably, as that's most like what is making this code slow. Loops are no longer as bad as they used to be, recent developments from TMW have made them almost comparable to vectorisation since R2016b.

Comment: Thank you for your comment +1 @Adriaan

Answer (score 0):

```
o = permute(1:50, [1,3,2]); % [  1 x   1 x 50]
center = R*o;               % [  1 x   1 x 50]
MX = abs(M-center)<dr;      % [100 x 100 x 50]
mm = MX.*B;                 % [100 x 100 x 50]

MX = reshape(MX, numel(M), numel(center)); % [100000 x 50]
mm = reshape(mm, numel(M), numel(center)); % [100000 x 50]

countB = sum(mm,1)./sum(mm==1); % [1 x 50]
count = sum(MX,1);              % [1 x 50]
```

Comment: Try it out, only then you know what is best for your specific case. I think the vectorized approach should be faster.